# Java 8 primitive stream to collection mapping methods

Tags: java, java-8, integer, java-stream

Is there any significant difference (in performance or best practices) between those two stream creation methods?

```
int[] arr2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

Arrays.stream(arr2)
      .map((in)->in*2)
      .mapToObj((in) -> new Integer(in))
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(()-> new ArrayList<>()));

Arrays.stream(arr2)
      .map(in->in*2)
      .boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(()-> new ArrayList<>()));
```

### EDIT

Thanks to Stack Community answers I can add some addons to question completeness for new readers:

As many pointed out, `.boxed()` IntStream method is defined as:

```
@Override
    public final Stream<Integer> boxed() {
        return mapToObj(Integer::valueOf);
    }
```

What basically re-defines issue to which one of following is better:

```
.mapToObj(in -> new Integer(in))
```

or

```
.mapToObj(in -> Integer.valueOf(in))
```

Comment: `.mapToObj((in) -> Integer.valueOf(in*2))`

Comment: Never use `new Integer`, always `Integer.valueOf`. Beside, use `Collectors.toList()`. For the rest, write a benchmark.

Comment: Besides all that `new Integer(int x)` is as well `Deprecated` since Java9. So just avoid using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [`boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) uses [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) which can retrieve some `Integer` instances from a [cache](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7).

So you should either use the version with `boxed()` (preferably), or use `Integer.valueOf` instead of `new Integer()`. Note that `boxed()` is in fact shorthand for [`mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/999dbd4192d0f819cb5224f26e9e7fa75ca6f289/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/IntPipeline.java#L232).

Comment: Tomasz, I'm choosing your answer as accepted one because: it's most up-voted, your reputation in relatively small in number comparing to other users that provided feedback and covers all aspects. And we are both Poles ;) JK!

Comment: @Tomas " I'm choosing your answer as accepted one because..." then maybe you should accept answer to indicate so ;-)

Comment: @Aomine Whoops, my bad :)

Answer (score 5):

The second is better as it creates no `Integer` objects in this example.

From the [JLS 5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

> If the value p being boxed is ... an int ... between -128 and 127 (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.

Generally speaking, you should not call `new` on wrapper types, but use their `static` factory methods - for example [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int))

Answer (score 4):

In terms of best practice, the second approach is preferable because when you want to box a primitive value `boxed` is created exactly for that purpose and does so in the most optimised way possible whereas `mapToObj`, although can be used to achieve the same thing, is not the idiomatic approach.

Further, it's advised not to use the primitive wrapper type constructors anymore and instead favour the `valueOf` methods, this is because these constructors have been deprecated as well as the fact that by using the `valueOf` it reduces memory footprint compared to the constructors leading to better performance.

Answer (score 4):

[`IntStream.boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()) uses [`Integer.valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) which is an optimised version* of [`Integer(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)).

Internally, `boxed()` is defined as `mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)`.

---

> <sup>*this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor `Integer(int)`, as this method is likely to yield *significantly better space and time performance* by caching frequently requested values.</sup>
>
> <sup><sup>[The Javadoc of `Integer.valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int))</sup></sup>

Answer (score 3):

The second one will effectively use the jvm's integer cache, thus it will be better both in performance, as well as a best practice (do not instantiate boxed types, rather let the vm do that for you).

You could imitate the same behavior if you changed the `new Integer(in)` with `Integer.valueOf(in)`

Answer (score 1):

For both performance and best practices, we should choose `boxed()` over `mapToObj((in) -> new Integer(in))`.

---

**Performance:**

See below `boxed()` source code (in the abstract class `IntPipeline<E_IN>` which  implements `IntStream`, in the `package java.util.stream` ):

```
@Override
    public final Stream<Integer> boxed() {
        return mapToObj(Integer::valueOf);
    }
```

So it is calling `mapToObj()` with `Integer::valueOf`. Note that by reusing cached values,`Integer::valueOf` is more efficient than `new Integer()` , so      we should choose `boxed()`.

---

**Best practice:**

Besides the performance difference,  with `boxed()` we write less, and it is easier to read.