# What is the difference between mapToObj(Integer::valueOf) and boxed()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose:

```
int[] arr;
```

Are there any difference between:

1. `Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()`
2. `Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)`

?

or more generic question:
What is the difference between `mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)` and `boxed()`? May be order/sorted does matter?

**UPD** my question is different from [Java 8 primitive stream to collection mapping methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53985683/java-8-primitive-stream-to-collection-mapping-methods) because my question is: **what is the exact difference**, but there asked about **primitive stream to collection mapping methods**.
There are many ways to collect stream to collections ( one of them mentioned there) but I'm interested in boxed Vs mapToObj, it's different. Yes there are an indirect and nebulous answer to my question too, but no any chance to find it directly ( at least it wasn't suggest to me automatically). The perfect answer is:

**none. internally: @Override public final Stream boxed() { return mapToObj(Integer::valueOf, 0); }** by Eugene

which wasn't even hint there, so my question is viable.

**UPD 2** Anyway I'd recommend to remain this question viable due to absolutely unsearchability neither here nor by google of mentioned [Java 8 primitive stream to collection mapping methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53985683/java-8-primitive-stream-to-collection-mapping-methods) for those who wanna discover boxed Vs mapToObj, I hadn't had a chance to find it before I asked this one.

Comment: none. internally: `@Override
    public final Stream<Integer> boxed() {
        return mapToObj(Integer::valueOf, 0);
    }`

Comment: @Eugene Please post this as an answer.

Comment: boxed is shorted, clearer, easier to read, and works on any type of primitive stream.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice too thin for an answer IMO, you could post it. I'll upvote.

Comment: @Eugene The problem is that comments can only be upvoted. If you post an answer it can be downvoted (if appropriate, although I doubt that's the case here) and more importantly, can be accepted by the user.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice right, but as said - this is too "thin" for my taste (at least at the moment) to post this as an answer.

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53985722/1746118) read *Yes, `boxed()` uses `Integer.valueOf`* and [the others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53985726/1746118) read as well *Internally,`boxed()` is defined as `mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)`.*  So, I guess the question remains a duplicate still.